# SQL BULK INSERT tries to insert all rows to insert into last column of first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm not completely familiar with SQL Server but I'm working on a project and trying to make the importing process as easy as possible. I'm importing a tsv file instead of a csv. The problem that I am getting is that when I try to use BULK INSERT, I get an error message, Bulk insert data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 15 (TY)

The only way I figured out what exactly it was doing was trying to just BULK INSERT 2 rows. It inserts the first row, but not the second row. I looked at the data and went to the last column, and sure enough, the 2nd row was in the last column. For the BULK INSERT, I'm using the code..

```
BULK INSERT Deal_Log
FROM 'C:\Users\Deals.tsv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n\t\r' 
)
GO
```

The FieldTerminator \t is for the tab separated values. I have researched how to BULK INSERT the tsv file and found an article by Aaron Bertrand (no longer available).

In this link, he says to play around with the RowTerminator to try to get it to work. I have tried \t\n, \n\r , \n, \r, \r\n\t, \n\r\t. So far the only ones that insert anything are \t\n, the one above, and \n\t, but it only inserts the first row and all remaining rows into the last column of row one. Here is the format of the tsv file..

```
182  20  THE DEALERSHIP, INC.  07/05/13  A34323  MODEL  MODE DESCRIPTION  BANKS NAME  1225.25  7856  6  KL8CB8384323DC43445  D
```

I looked at the data in the tsv file and there is not a tabbed space before or after the columns. If more information is needed, please let me know! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the Rowterminator was not needed. It didn't solve all of my problems using the bulk insert but it did help once I figured this out. The biggest issue I was running into was fields being cut off and placed on another line. This is one of the reason why the truncation was happening. Checking the original csv download is important to make sure that everything will go smoothly. It was a unique situation since my company still uses a software application that should have died when DOS did.

Answer (score 2):

probably a Unix file, see here [BULK INSERT data where the row terminator is a linefeed in SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/bulk-insert-data-where-the)

you have to use `CHAR(10)` with dynamic SQL

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave it a shot, but now I'm getting a error..Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".